# web2y escaping of {{ abc }} in view HTML

Tags: view, web2py

how do I add the following string {{ cake }} to a view but have only have it displayed as {{ cake }}. Web2py tries to replace with a variable that doesn't exist. I just want to make use of double open {{ and close }} within the view HTML without web2py searching variables.

Is there an escape character that is needed?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to wrap the opening delimiter in quotes inside a pair of template delimiters:

```
{{='{{'}} cake }}
```

Note, there is no need to wrap the closing delimiter because the template engine will only process it if there is an unmatched opening delimiter earlier in the template.

Another option is to define a helper function (preferably in a model file so it is available in all views), such as:

```
def wrap(content):
    return '{{%s}}' % content
```

and in a template:

```
{{=wrap('cake')}}
```

Finally, if the issue is that you are using a Javascript framework (e.g., Vue.js) that uses the same template delimiters as web2py, you can dynamically (e.g., per controller action) change the web2py delimiters via `response.delimiters`. For example:

```
response.delimiters = ('%{', '}%')
```

Also, note that most Javascript frameworks allow you to specify custom delimiters as well, so you may find it easier to make the change there rather than in web2py.